# Cannot create PostGIS data store in GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am trying to add a PostGIS database a data store in my GeoServer installation but I keep getting this error:

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Le type d'authentification 10 n'est pas supporté. Vérifiez que vous avez configuré le fichier pg_hba.conf pour inclure l'adresse IP du client ou le sous-réseau et qu'il utilise un schéma d'authentification supporté par le pilote.)

Comment: Did you try doing what the message suggests?

Answer (score 3):

The JDBC driver in use does not support the new SCRAM-SHA-256 encryption, you'll have to change it back to md5, or try upgrading the PostgreQL JDBC driver.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppor

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was the following:

I modified the pg_hba file located in: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\pg_hba, changing the connection method from "scram-sha-256" to "trust" on all lines.

[image]

Comment: This is an English language site. Please use English