# Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused)

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a PostgreSQL server with PostGIS extension enabled running on docker with port 5432 exposed.
I'm able to connect using
`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d db`

but when I try to use the same credentials to add a store using GeoServer I get the following error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
```

this is my pg_hba.conf file as found on /var/lib/postgresql/data

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

I'm using GeoServer 2.25

Comment: Could it be that Geoserver does not support scram-sha-256? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408887/cannot-create-postgis-data-store-in-geoserver